# Zend DB query() - how do I perform a database update?

Tags: zend-framework

The last line of this code seems to return an object but does not perform the database query. What do I change to get this to actually perform the database update?

```
$sql = "UPDATE vi_admin_email SET processed_send_list = '?', status = '?' WHERE id = '?'";
$bind = array($addresses,$status,$id);
$res = $this->getAdapter()->query($sql,$bind);
```

Here is a var dump of the object in $res:

```
object(Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo)[102]
  protected '_fetchMode' => int 2
  protected '_stmt' => 
    object(PDOStatement)[100]
      public 'queryString' => string 'UPDATE vi_admin_email SET processed_send_list = '?', status = '?' WHERE id = '?'' (length=80)
  protected '_adapter' => 
    object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql)[43]
      protected '_pdoType' => string 'mysql' (length=5)
      protected '_numericDataTypes' => 
        array
          0 => int 0
          1 => int 1
          2 => int 2
          'INT' => int 0
          'INTEGER' => int 0
          'MEDIUMINT' => int 0
          'SMALLINT' => int 0
          'TINYINT' => int 0
          'BIGINT' => int 1
          'SERIAL' => int 1
          'DEC' => int 2
          'DECIMAL' => int 2
          'DOUBLE' => int 2
          'DOUBLE PRECISION' => int 2
          'FIXED' => int 2
          'FLOAT' => int 2
      protected '_defaultStmtClass' => string 'Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo' (length=21)
      protected '_config' => 
        array
          'host' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
          'username' => string 'root' (length=4)
          'password' => string '' (length=0)
          'dbname' => string 'vi' (length=2)
          'charset' => null
          'persistent' => boolean false
          'options' => 
            array
              ...
          'driver_options' => 
            array
              ...
      protected '_fetchMode' => int 2
      protected '_profiler' => 
        object(Zend_Db_Profiler)[44]
          protected '_queryProfiles' => 
            array
              ...
          protected '_enabled' => boolean false
          protected '_filterElapsedSecs' => null
          protected '_filterTypes' => null
      protected '_defaultProfilerClass' => string 'Zend_Db_Profiler' (length=16)
      protected '_connection' => 
        object(PDO)[85]
      protected '_caseFolding' => int 0
      protected '_autoQuoteIdentifiers' => boolean true
      protected '_allowSerialization' => boolean true
      protected '_autoReconnectOnUnserialize' => boolean false
  protected '_attribute' => 
    array
      empty
  protected '_bindColumn' => 
    array
      empty
  protected '_bindParam' => 
    array
      empty
  protected '_sqlSplit' => 
    array
      0 => string 'UPDATE vi_admin_email SET processed_send_list = , status =  WHERE id = ' (length=71)
  protected '_sqlParam' => 
array
  0 => string 'UPDATE vi_admin_email SET processed_send_list = , status =  WHERE id = ' (length=71)
```

protected '_queryId' => null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update an entry in Zend Framework you do as follow :

```
$data = array(
    'processed_send_list' => $addresses,
    'status' => $status
);

$dbAdapter = $this->getAdapter();

$where = $dbApdapter->quoteInto('id = ?', $id);

$this->update($data, $where);
```

With `Zend_Db_Table`, the data to be updated is specfied in an `associative array` as the first parameter. The data provided will be escaped when the query is executed. You also have to include a `where` statement as a string, like `id = 1` as the second parameter. In the above example, the `quoteInto` is optionnal as you can write the where manually, but the value will not be escaped if you do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I read "query" but you asked about "update".

So the statement would be:

$res->execute().

Forget what I wrote before.

Comment: Hmmm.. that doesn't work. When I check the sql it is going through without binding the params, ie, there were three ? placeholders instead of the actual params.

Answer (score 0):

Try this single line of code,

```
$res = $this->getAdapter()->query("UPDATE vi_admin_email SET processed_send_list = '$addresses', status = '$status' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Comment: Yes I already tried that and it works... but I want to bind params to the sql statement.